# iOS: selecting option returns null first time, not second time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have an iOS application where you select an option before you log in. The way it works is that you click on the button that says "Select", then it takes you to a UITableViewController which shows you the options, you select the option, and it takes you back to the previous menu with the text replaced with your selection (and a hidden ID saved, too).

During the update of the information (which takes place in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) I call NSLog on the object. The first time I call it, it returns null (BUT for some reason the text still changes!) and the second time I call it, it works! Why doesn't it work the first time????

Thanks

Comment: lol why are you not legally allowed to post your code? im pretty sure your code is not so special to be illegal when shown.

Comment: Are you serious? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement

Comment: Change your variable names. Make up a different context.

Answer (score 1):

Do you put the NSLog line before the previous view push back code ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable was named incorrectly. I don't know why XCode didn't just tell me this instead of giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but that's what happened.